# Docker git remote deploy lock

Tags: python, git, docker, dokku

I am attempting to push code to a remote git repository. After committing the code, when I run `git push origin master` command,  I run into this error.

```
remote: + local LOCK_TYPE=exclusive
remote: + local APP_DEPLOY_LOCK_FILE=/home/dokku/example/.deploy.lock
remote: + local 'LOCK_WAITING_MSG=example currently has a deploy lock in place. Waiting...'
remote: + local 'LOCK_FAILED_MSG=example currently has a deploy lock in place. Exiting...'
remote: + acquire_advisory_lock /home/dokku/example/.deploy.lock exclusive 'dash-stroom-app-v1 currently has a deploy lock in place. Waiting...' 'example currently has a deploy lock in place. Exiting...'
remote: + declare 'desc=acquire advisory lock'
remote: + local LOCK_FILE=/home/dokku/example/.deploy.lock LOCK_TYPE=exclusive 'LOCK_WAITING_MSG=example currently has a deploy lock in place. Waiting...' 'LOCK_FAILED_MSG=example currently has a deploy lock in place. Exiting...'
remote: + local LOCK_FD=200
remote: + local SHOW_MSG=true
remote: + eval 'exec 200>/home/dokku/example/.deploy.lock'
remote: ++ exec
remote: + [[ exclusive == \w\a\i\t\i\n\g ]]
remote: + flock -n 200
remote: + dokku_log_fail 'example currently has a deploy lock in place. Exiting...'
remote: + declare 'desc=log fail formatter'
remote: + echo 'example currently has a deploy lock in place. Exiting...'
remote: example currently has a deploy lock in place. Exiting...
remote: + exit 1
remote: + exit_code=1
remote: + set -e
remote: + [[ 1 -eq 10 ]]
remote: + implemented=1
remote: + [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
remote: + exit 1
To https://example.com/GIT/example
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://example.com/GIT/example'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/3796
and tried

`sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y herokuish`

Managed to deploy afterwards.